# What is the one-sided Fourier transform of a constant?

Tags: fourier-transform

A definition of the Fourier transform commonly used is (I always forget which convention of normalization to use) \begin{align}f(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i \omega t}f(t) dt\end{align}
For a constant function $f(t)=1$, this evaluates to the Dirac delta function, \begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i \omega t}dt = 2\pi\delta(\omega)\end{align}
**Question**:

What is the one-sided Fourier transform of a constant function\begin{align}\int_{0}^\infty e^{i \omega t}dt = ?\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put in a cutoff
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{i\omega t}e^{-\epsilon t}dt= \frac 1{i\omega -\epsilon}
$$
So the Fourier transform  of the Heaviside step function $\theta(t)$ is the $\epsilon\to 0$ limit
$$
\mathcal{F}[\theta](\omega)= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left\{\frac{-i}{\omega-i\epsilon}\right\}= P\left(\frac{1}{i\omega}\right)+\pi \delta(\omega),
$$
where "$P$" is the principal part distribution.
(I added edit to show connection with @Thomas Fritsch's answer)

Answer (score 2):

You look for the Fourier transform of the step function:
$$f(t)=\begin{cases}
1, &\text{for }t > 0 \\
0, &\text{for }t < 0
\end{cases}$$

The solution is well known
(see for example at [Fourier transform of typical signals](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node3.html)):

$$F(\omega)=\frac{1}{i\omega} + \pi\delta(\omega)$$

Depending on your sign and normalization convention
you may need to modify this by a minus sign or by a $2\pi$ factor.